# ORACLE 11g does not allow you to insert/update a string literal date into a date column

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I just converted from Oracle10g to Oracle11g. Suddenly some of the Oracle java classes that insert into date columns stopped working. I will list what is and is not working in both 10G and 11G

The Actual Error: ( Oracle 11g jdbc )

1. `select sysdate from dual` returns 2014-03-14 14:44:58.0
2. `update users set expirationdate=to_date('2014-06-13','YYYY-MM-DD') where userId = 'NBKVLJN'`  ( successful )
3. `update users set lastModifiedDate=sysdate where userId = 'NBKVLJN'` ( successful )
4. `update users set expirationdate='2014-06-13' where userId = 'NBKVLJN'`   ( failure ) 
   err=java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

The very same sequence above works in all cases with Oracle 10g.

Comment: You don't show us the actual Java code. But #4 is bad coding practice because you rely on implicit data type casting (string to date) which is a bad idea. Anywy in Java use a `PreparedStatement` and instances of `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.sql.Date` to update a `DATE` column in the database. Don't pass strings for date values.

Comment: You don't show us the column definition either.

Answer (score 0):

I was told to always use the `TO_DATE()` function when building a SQL statement string for Oracle.

I am actually surprised that option 4 worked in 10g!  Perhaps it is a bug which has since been fixed?

Perhaps in the table in the 10g database, the `expirationdate` column was a `VARCHAR2` instead of a `DATE`?